# How to get specific SQL counts for each year?

Tags: sql, count, datepart

I am trying to get specific counts of bike sales per year, but now I'm only getting a total count of sales over the 5 year period and not broken up by specific years.

--CURRENT CODE:

```
Select datepart(year, C.TransactionDate) AS SalesYear,
    SUM(COUNT(B.SerialNumber)) OVER() AS CountOfSerialNumber
FROM BIKE..Bicycle AS B
    INNER JOIN BIKE..CustomerTransaction AS C on B.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE ModelType = 'Mountain' AND
    TransactionDate BETWEEN '20000101' AND '20041231'
GROUP BY datepart(year, C.TransactionDate)
ORDER BY datepart(year, C.TransactionDate) ASC
```

--And my resulting output reads:

```
SalesYear | CountOfSerialNumber
2000        9431
2001        9431
2002        9431
2003        9431
2004        9431
```

Comment: Why are you using `SUM()` and `OVER()`, what's wrong with `COUNT(B.SerialNumber)`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column TransactionDate data type?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the count without using `SUM` or `OVER`. `OVER` can be used to get a percentage of the total, if that's something you wanted to do.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, C.TransactionDate) AS SalesYear, COUNT(B.SerialNumber) AS Quantity,
       COUNT(B.SerialNumber) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(B.SerialNumber)) OVER() AS Percentage
FROM BIKE..Bicycle AS B
INNER JOIN BIKE..CustomerTransaction AS C ON C.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
WHERE B.ModelType = 'Mountain' AND C.TransactionDate BETWEEN '20000101' AND '20041231'
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, C.TransactionDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, C.TransactionDate) ASC
```